# sqlite3 database locked on multiple inserts

Tags: database, bash, sqlite, locking

I am using a couple bash script that writes to multiple tables "never the same" in the same sqlite database.

I am getting database locked errors, I did read around, but I am not sure that I should be getting this error given that I am writing to different tables in the same database, never to the same table in the same database.

Did I misunderstand this ?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

SQLite uses one file for all the tables. It locks the whole file, not single tables.

As a workaround, you might need to repeat the operation later after a time interval several times, until it succeeds.